# How do I setup my Graphics so that a user can change the size and stay in proportion?

Tags: java, oop, graphics, parameter-passing

Hello fellow programmers, I have browsed your site for some time now and have been helped time and time again so thank you for that. I now have a question that I cant find a good answer for. I have a "self Portrait" that I have made using Graphics in Java, I have broken up the drawing of the mouth, eyes, nose, hair etc. into separate methods and then call them all in my drawHead method. I am at a loss as how to allow a user to change the width and height and still have all the components stay in proper proportion. Here is a snippet of my code. I can post the whole thing if you like just let me know.

```
public void drawEyes(int baseX, int top) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    eyeball = new Color(0xFFFFFF);
    eye = new Color(0x007FFF);
    pupil = new Color (0x000000);
    g.setColor(eyeball);
    g.fillOval(baseX+50, top+50, 50, 35);
    g.fillOval(baseX+150, top+50, 50, 35);
    g.setColor(eye);
    g.fillOval(baseX+65,top+60, 20, 20);
    g.fillOval(baseX+165,top+60, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(pupil);
    g.fillOval(baseX+70,top+65, 10, 10);
    g.fillOval(baseX+170,top+65, 10, 10);
}

public void drawMouth(int baseX, int top) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g.setColor(eyeball);
    g.fillArc(baseX+50, top+140, 150, 65, 180, 180);
    g.setColor(pupil);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    g.drawLine(baseX+55, top+173, baseX+55, top+183);
    g.drawLine(baseX+75, top+173, baseX+75, top+196);
    g.drawLine(baseX+100, top+173, baseX+100, top+202);
    g.drawLine(baseX+125, top+173, baseX+125, top+204);
    g.drawLine(baseX+150, top+173, baseX+150, top+202);
    g.drawLine(baseX+175, top+173, baseX+175, top+196);
    g.drawLine(baseX+195, top+173, baseX+195, top+183);
    g.drawArc(baseX+45, top+140, 160, 50, 200, 140);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
}

public void drawNose(int baseX, int top) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; 
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g.drawLine(baseX+125, top+80, baseX+100, top+130);
    g.drawLine(baseX+100, top+130, baseX+130, top+130);
}


public void drawHead(int baseX, int top) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    head = new Color(0xFFDFC4);
    g.setColor(head);
    g.fillOval(baseX, top, 250, 250);
    drawEyes(baseX, top);
    drawMouth(baseX, top);
    drawNose(baseX, top);
    drawHair(baseX, top);
}
public void paint(Graphics g) {     
    top = (this.getHeight()/2)-125; 
    baseX = (this.getWidth()/2)-125;
    drawHead(baseX, top);
}
```

Comment: "Proportional" is the same as saying "use ratios".

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I think what you need to do is make a method that takes the "baseX" and "top" parameters, sets them to a variable, then multiplies this variable by a specific value. As Radiodef commented, these values are ratios.

For instance:

- mouth might be "baseX * 2" by "top"
- nose might be "baseX" by "top"
- and the actual head might be "baseX * 3" by "top *3".

I'm not completely sure what your separations are, but this should help.

Comment: I appreciate the assistance. I do understand that these must be ratios in order to maintain proportion only thing I was having trouble with was (this is for an assignment btw) he want one time calculations done in the init() method of the applet I am using to create the portrait. The only way I can get the portrait to stretch and stay proper per the requirements was to take every line of code used for drawing and multiply each value individually per the multiplier. (60 lines just for the hair but it looks good lol) This is totally different than anything else we have done so I am having issues

Comment: This is the only way I could think of fixing your problem, but, yes, it would take a lot of code changes. The time it would take may not be worth it in the end.